# Multiple Serializer within the same view.list call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a simple model that can contain some sensitive information

```py
class Organization(Model):
  name = CharField()
  is_private = BooleanField()
  
  # the following information is sensitive
  code = CharField()
  employee_count = IntegerField()

  # other confidential fields...
```

I am using regular *ModelViewSet* and *ModelSerializer* for this model.

when calling the `list` action of the viewset (GET `organizations/`) I would like to have my **organizations serialized differently depending on whether they are private** (meaning different json response):

- show all the fields if the organization is not private
- only name if it is private

```py
class PrivateOrganizationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  """ Serializer used for private organizations """
  fields = ["name", "is_private"]
  model = Organization

class PublicOrganizationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  """ Serializer used for public organizations """
  fields = ["name", "is_private", "code", "employee_count"]
  model = Organization
```

example of json response:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "TBT inc.",
    "is_private": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Forturama",
    "is_private": false,
    "code": "X25GT",
    "employee_count": 56
  }
]
```

What I already tried:

- overriding `get_serializer()` of viewset => this doesn't fit as the same serializer applies for all objects of the list
- using `serializers.MethodField()` => not efficient because I have many fields that I'd need to handle

Comment: "I would like to have my organizations serialized differently depending on whether they are private". Do you mean the json response content returned? Also, one more question: You're creating more than one serializer to do that? If yes, could you insert the code here?

Comment: Yes I mean the json response. Also yes I was thinking of 2 different serializers (I added examples) but if there is another solution I'll take it.

Comment: How about overriding the to_representation method of the existing serializer? This can avoid to create two serializers and the representation could be different based on the class instance. However, depending of the situation, creating two serializers could be the best clean idea.

Comment: can you give me an example of overriding the to_representation method in my case?
Also for having 2 serializers, how can I switch from one to another depending on the row?

Comment: ok, sure. Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Option 01 - Overriding the to_representation method:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class ExampleSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = "__all__"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if isinstance(instance, Example) and not instance.is_private:
            return super().to_representation(instance)

        result = dict(custom_field=instance.name, another_custom_field=instance.is_private)

        return result
```

Option 02 - Using two serializers in one view:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
from .serializers import ExampleSerializer, AnotherExampleSerializer


class AnyView(ListAPIView):
    # Create a new attribute to store the serializers
    serializers_classes = (ExampleSerializer, AnotherExampleSerializer)

    # One way to do it
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if <some_specific_condition>:
            self.serializer_class = self.serializers_classes[0]
            return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)

        self.serializer_class = self.serializers_classes[1]
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Another way to do it
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if <some_specific_conditition>:
            serializer = self.serializers_classes[0](self.get_queryset(), many=True)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                return Response(data=serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)

            return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer = self.serializers_classes[1](self.get_queryset(), many=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Maybe you will need to override the get_queryset to return the fields differently if private is True.

In my opinion, overriding the to_representation method of serializer will be enough to do it.